# Why won't this react app written in typescript display login page content?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I can see the content on the home page and navigation menu at the top.  When I click on the Login link (or Register or My Data), I only see the navigation menu, the Home page content disappears as expected.

It's probably a problem with the `<Route>` part, I had some trouble getting that to work without errors being displayed.  My package.json file has this:  "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0"

The Developer Tools debug console doesn't show any errors.
VS Code compiled it fine without any errors to.

Here's the App.tsx file:

```
import LoginPage from './user/LoginPage';
import RegisterPage from './user/RegisterPage';
import MyDataPage from './user/MyDataPage';
import PublicRoute from './user/routes/PublicRoute'
import PrivateRoute from './user/routes/PrivateRoute'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="container">
      <nav className="nav">
        <Link to="/" className="button">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/user/login" className="button">Login</Link>
        <Link to="/user/register" className="button">Register</Link>
        <Link to="/user/mydata" className="button">My Data</Link>
      </nav>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/user/login/*" element={<PublicRoute path="/user/login/*" element={<LoginPage />} />} />
        <Route path="/user/register/*" element={<PublicRoute path="/user/register/*" element={<RegisterPage />} />} />
        <Route path="/user/mydata/*" element={<PrivateRoute path="/user/mydata/*" element={<MyDataPage />} />} /> 
      </Routes>
    </div>
  </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to my app</h1>
      <p>This is the home page</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here's the code for PublicRoute.tsx:

```
import { ComponentType } from 'react';
import { getToken } from '../AuthService'
import { Navigate, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';

interface PublicRouteProps {
    path: string;
    element: React.ReactElement;
  }

function PublicRoute({element: Component, ...rest}: PublicRouteProps): JSX.Element {
   
    
    return (
        <Routes>
        <Route
        {...rest}
        element={
                    !getToken() ? Component : <Navigate to="/user/mydata" />
                }
        />
        </Routes>
    )
}

export default PublicRoute;
```

Here's the code for Login.tsx:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { setUserSession } from './AuthService'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const loginUrl = "https://{somewhere}.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/login"

function LoginPage() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const submitHandler = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(username.trim() === '' || password.trim() === '') {
        setErrorMessage('Both username and password are required.');
        return;
    }
    setErrorMessage('');
    console.log("submit button is pressed.")

    const requestConfig = {
        headers: {
            'x-api-key': '{some awesome api key}'
        }
    }

    const requestBody = {
        username: username,
        password: password
    }
    axios.post(loginUrl, requestBody, requestConfig).then(response => {
      setUserSession(response.data.user, response.data.token);
      navigate('/user/mydata')
    }).catch(error => {
        if (error.response && (error.response.status === 401 || error.response.status === 403)) {
            setErrorMessage(error.response.data.message);
            setSuccessMessage('');
        } else {
            setErrorMessage('Sorry...backend server error.  Please try again later. Error=' + error);
            setSuccessMessage('');
          }
    })
}  


  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Login here</h1>
       <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <fieldset>
              <legend>Loing Credentials</legend>
              <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                      <label >Username:</label>
                      <input type="text" value={username} onChange={event => setUsername(event.target.value)} /> <br />
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                      <label >Password:</label>
                      <input type="password" value={password} onChange={event => setPassword(event.target.value)} /> <br />
                  </div>
              </div>
          </fieldset>
          <div className="row">
              <div className="col-sm-12">
                  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
              </div>
          </div>
      </form>
      {errorMessage && <p className="card error">{errorMessage}</p>}
      {successMessage && <p className="card">{successMessage}</p>}
    </div>
    )
}

export default LoginPage;
```

Comment: _"the Home page content disappears as expected"_... this doesn't sound like a bug if it's expected

Comment: @DrewReese I just meant there's not really a question or problem described above.

Comment: @Phil Yeah, not overtly asked in the post, but it's encapsulated in the statement "When I click on the Login link (or Register or My Data), I only see the navigation menu, the Home page content disappears as expected.", meaning, the home page went away as expected, but the new page *didn't* show up. The overt question is the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The `PublicRoute` route component renders descendent routes and descendent routes build their routes relative to the parent route. The `PublicRoute` component passes through the `path` prop to the descendent route.

For example this route for the `LoginPage`.

```
function PublicRoute({
  element: Component, ...rest
}: PublicRouteProps): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        {...rest} // <-- path passed here
        element={!getToken()
          ? Component
          : <Navigate to="/user/mydata" />
        }
      />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

```
<Route
  path="/user/login/*"
  element={(
    <PublicRoute
      path="/user/login/*" // <-- descendent route path passed
      element={<LoginPage />}
    />
  )}
/>
```

This means that `Component` is rendered on path `"/user/login/user/login"`, which is most certainly not what you intended.

## Solution

You could likely resolve the issue by passing `"/"` as the descendent route path so the path resolves as `"/user/login"`, e.g.:

```
<Route
  path="/user/login/*"
  element={<PublicRoute path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />}
/>
```

### However

You are *overcomplicating* the routing. Convert `PublicRoute` and `PrivateRoute` into layout routes, e.g. routed components that render an `Outlet` for their nested routes to render their content into.

See [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) and [Outlets](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets) for more details.

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

function PublicRoute(): JSX.Element {
  return !getToken()
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/user/mydata" replace />
}
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
        <nav className="nav">
          <Link to="/" className="button">Home</Link>
          <Link to="/user/login" className="button">Login</Link>
          <Link to="/user/register" className="button">Register</Link>
          <Link to="/user/mydata" className="button">My Data</Link>
        </nav>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route element={<PublicRoute />}>
            <Route path="/user/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
            <Route path="/user/register" element={<RegisterPage />} />
          </Route>
          <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
            <Route path="/user/mydata" element={<MyDataPage />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```